How to change the value of a column based on a condition and an inner join?
I have two Pandas dataframes; let's call them df_a and df_b.
df_a looks like this:
account | threshold | standardised_threshold
--------|-----------|-----------------------
A       | 39.5      | 40
B       | 42.6      | 45
C       | 47.4      | 45
D       | 53.5      | 50

df_b looks like this:
account
-------
B
C

In df_a, I want to add 5 to the standardised_threshold column for all rows that fulfil both of the following conditions:

Account is in df_b
The threshold column in df_a is below a fixed number (let's say 45 for this example)

In other words, df_a should look like this:
account | threshold | standardised_threshold
--------|-----------|-----------------------
A       | 39.5      | 40
B       | 42.6      | 50
C       | 47.4      | 45
D       | 53.5      | 50

Does anyone know the best way to do this please?

You can just check if account is in the desired set and update only relevant values by addressing them via .loc
df_a = pd.DataFrame({
    "account": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    "threshold": [39.5, 42.6, 47.4, 53.5],
    "standardised_threshold": [40, 45, 45, 50],
})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({
     "account": ["B", "C"],
})

df_a.loc[
    df_a["account"].isin(set(df_b.account))
        & (df_a["threshold"] < 45),
    "standardised_threshold"
] += 5

print(df_a)

Output:
  account  threshold  standardised_threshold
0       A       39.5                      45
1       B       42.6                      50
2       C       47.4                      45
3       D       53.5                      50


condition = condition = (df_a['account'].isin(df_b['account'])) & (df_a['threshold'] < 45)

df_a.loc[condition, 'standardised_threshold'] += 5


Use DataFrame.loc with chaindex conditions with Series.isin for test membership and Series.lt for test less like N:
N = 45
mask = df_a['account'].isin(df_b['account']) & df_a['threshold'].lt(N)
df_a.loc[mask, 'standardised_threshold'] += 5
print (df_a)
  account  threshold  standardised_threshold
0       A       39.5                      40
1       B       42.6                      50
2       C       47.4                      45
3       D       53.5                      50

